# Tensorflow error: ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_4 is incompatible with the layer

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and recently startet course on udacity.
I have fashion mnist dataset and model

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu,
                       input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])
```

After compiling and starting  `ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape (None, None, 28, 28)`

I really have no idea what happened, can someone please help me?
Thank you!

Comment: what's the shape of your training dataset (so like whats the output of`print(X_train.shape)`)?

Comment: hello!
this error appears when I run cells with model and model.compile and with this 
result of model.summary()  stays the same except for model name (first its "sequential", then "sequential_1" and so on)

X_train is generated with this code
BATCH_SIZE = 5

train_dataset = train_dataset.cache().repeat().shuffle(num_train_examples).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
test_dataset = test_dataset.cache().batch(BATCH_SIZE)

it's a set of 60 000 images 28 * 28 * 1

Comment: @JohnKeats, The error states that the last dimension of the input data you are passing to the model is not 1. The input shape mentioned in the model is  (28, 28, 1) but your data is of shape (None, None, 28, 28), please reshape the train_dataset to (28, 28, 1) and try again. Thank you!